# Can pagination work within a cog extension for a discord bot? SOLVED

Tags: python-3.x, pagination, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot that interacts with an API. I had a large command file and wanted to break it up so I started implementing cogs into the code. After the transition, I started testing commands and came across an issue.

This command below is a pagination command and creates an embed list to do the pagination.

This WAS working before I moved it to a different file.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with pagination from DiscordUtils and out-of-the-box Cogs?

NOT ON REWRITE BRANCH

```
@commands.command(name="getLeaderboard")
    async def getErbsLeaderboard(self, ctx, gameMode: str):
        mode = gameModeSwitch(gameMode)
        if not mode:
          embedVar.add_field(name='getErbsLeaderboard', value=f'Game mode was incorrect. Please input any ONE of these:| Solo(s) | Duo(s) | Squad(s) |')
          await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
          return
        leaders = await getLeaderboard(baseUrl=BASE_URL, seasonId='1', teamMode=mode, apiKey=API_KEY)
        if leaders:
          embeds:list = []
          i = 1
          for page in leaders:
            embeds.append(discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name=f"Rank {i}-{i+24}", value=f"{''.join(page)}"))
            i+=25 
            paginator = Pagination.AutoEmbedPaginator(ctx)
            await paginator.run(embeds)
        else:
          embedVar.add_field(name="getErbsSquadLeaderboard", value=f"No Leaderboard was found.", inline=False)
          await ctx.send(embed=embeds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Paginator and the run shouldn't be in the for loop. They need to be outside of for loop. Leaving this here if anyone has any brain fart like me.